# google map api Error: Error in property <waypoints>:

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to set some waypoints on google maps api but get get the following error. I know it has something to do with setting an object but I cant seem to get it right. Nor can I find any exact articles on it.

```
Error: Error in property <waypoints>: (Invalid value: Ballybricken, Waterford, Ireland,The Glen, Waterford (Error in element at position 0: (Unknown property <0>)))
```

My code

```
var waypts = ["Ballybricken, Waterford, Ireland", "The Glen, Waterford"];
drawPolyline('Waterford Regional Hospital', 'Hillview, Waterford, Ireland', waypts);


function drawPolyline(source,destination,waypoints){
        // show route between the points
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
        {
            suppressMarkers: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
            polylineOptions: { strokeColor: '#000000', strokeOpacity: 0.5 } 
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        var request = {
            origin:source, 
            destination:destination,
            waypoints:waypoints,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
            {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 5):

A waypoint is not an address or latLng, it's an object that consists of a (required) `location`-member and an (optional) `stopover`-member, so your array should look like this:

```
var waypts = [{location:"Ballybricken"},
              {location:"Waterford"},
              {location:"Ireland"},
              {location:"The Glen"},
              {location:"Waterford"}];
```